# multidimensional array - fill with post

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying hard to get a form working, here is some background information: I have a php form that should be dynamically expandable. I am using a multidimensional array with description and quantity e.g.

```
[0][0] blankets [0][1]2 [1][0] cusions [0][1]3 [2][0] sheets [0][1]5
[3][0] teddys [0][1]12 empty form field

echo '<td><input type="submit" class="plusminus" name="addiere" value="+">&nbsp;';?>
```

At the top of the page:

```
if(isset($_POST['addiere']))
{   $newindex=count($_POST['taetigkeiten'])+1;
    $_POST['taetigkeiten'][]=array("Teppich verlegen","4");     
    $anzahlteileinsaetze=$anzahlteileinsaetze+1;
    if (count($_POST['taetigkeiten']) == count($_POST['taetigkeiten'], COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
    {
        echo 'array is not multidimensionalxx';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'array is multidimensionalx';
    }
}
```

So in the first step, I'd like to simply add `array("Teppich verlegen","4");` to my array `$_POST['taetigkeiten']`. Later of course this should be the values entered in a new field. So the form always contains two empty fields below the foreach-loop. The problem I have, is the key. I loop over the array as follows:

```
   foreach ($_POST['taetigkeiten'] as $properties) { 
        if(is_array($properties)) echo "peeppeep";
        print_r(array_keys($properties));
        echo $properties['beschreibung'];
    }
```

The print_r gives me the correct keys. But the page said: `Undefined index: beschreibung`.
But is correct outputted by array keys?

Comment: Use `print_r($properties)` and check if there is `[beshreibung] => ...` line.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for that fast reply. That print_r is what I tried to mention. The output:

Array ( ['taetigkeit'] => kleben ) 
Notice: Undefined index: taetigkeit in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 98
So it says there is the key taetigkeit but it unidentified...

Comment: Hi, first thanks for that fast reply. That print_r is what I tried to mention. The output: